# Only the second function is called, Android studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

I followed a tutorial on Camerax from the Android Studio website, and I wanted the camera button when pressed to take a picture from the front and the back camera, the problem is only the second function is called.

Ctrl + F `THE PROBLEM IS HERE` to find the two functions.

MainActivity.kt file:

```
package com.android.example.cameraxapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.video.*
import androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture
import androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import android.provider.MediaStore

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.os.Build
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import com.nasro.camerax.R
import com.nasro.camerax.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var cameraSelector: CameraSelector
     var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

     var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
     var recording: Recording? = null

     lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)

        }

        // Set up the listeners for take photo and video capture buttons
        viewBinding.imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {start()}
        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
        }
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

     fun captureVideo() {}

    fun start() {

        //THE PROBLEM IS HERE, THE PROBLEM IS HERE, THE PROBLEM IS HERE.

        startCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA)
        startCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA)
    }

    private fun startCamera(pizza:CameraSelector) {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.viewFinder).surfaceProvider)
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, pizza, preview, imageCapture)
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
            takePhoto()
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        var imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time stamped name and MediaStore entry.
        val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
            .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
            }
        }

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
            .Builder(contentResolver,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                contentValues)
            .build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun
                        onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${output.savedUri}"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
            }
        )

    }

    fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }
    val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
        .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
        }
    }

    companion object {
         const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
         const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
         const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
         val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            mutableListOf (
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ).apply {
            }.toTypedArray()
    }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
        IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: how front and back at same time will open?

Comment: I'm expecting that the second one will wait till the first finishes

Answer (score 2):

What if instead of calling it twice on the button click you called the front camera only, and then call startCamera() again in the onImageSaved function conditionally. You'd just have to pass the value of the param from startCamera() to takePicture() or set a global variable.

```
override fun
onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults){
   val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${output.savedUri}"
   Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   Log.d(TAG, msg)
   if (pizza == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA) {
      startCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA)
      } 
         }
```